# Best way to store several ArrayLists in ORMLite for ApplicationSettings

Tags: java, database, orm, ormlite

Right now I am trying to persist the Settings of an Application to my `DB` with the help of `ORMLite`.

Well my settings consist of different `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>` or maybe a `Map` actually just a bunch of `Strings`. So my question is, what datatype should I use for such a scenario and optional maybe you could also provide me a small `code example`.

Right now I tried different things, but I never was happy with the solution. I tried stuff like:

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> configurationMap;

private String[] stringArr1;
private String[] stringArr2;

private ArrayList<String> arrList1;
```

But when it comes to setup the `DB Datatypes` I always think, "I don't want an extra table to store the data" or "having a map serialized to the DB sucks...".

Maybe anybody has an idea how to solve this in a nice and convenient way?

Comment: Realised it now with ArrayList. This works quite nice `@DatabaseField(id = false, foreign = false, columnName = ConfigurationModel.SAM_ACC_VALUES_TO_IGNORE, dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
 public ArrayList<String> samAccountValuesToIgnore;`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441595/how-to-store-the-arraylist-in-ormlite-database/31598771#31598771 for an easier solution

Answer (score 10):

For the arrayList you can simply do the following :

```
public class YourClass{
    @GeneratedId
    private int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private Collection<MyString> bunchOfStrings = new ArrayList<MyString>();
    ...
}
```

In the MyString class you have the following :

```
public class MyString{
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
    private YourClass yourClass;

     @DatabaseField
     private String text;
    ....
}
```

And that's all

Comment: Why do you save the `ForeignCollectionField ` as `Collection<MyString>` instead of as `ArrayList<MyString>`? Can you save it directly as `ArrayList<MyString>`? When working with the `bunchOfStrings` object, do I just cast it to `ArrayList<MyString>` whenever using it?

Comment: @Yuchen To tell you the truth I don't remember why I was using collection instead of ArrayList (It's been more than 3 years). But what I remember is I was obliged to use the collection instead of ArrayList I think it was some limitation by the time.

Comment: @DrissBounouar, thanks for getting back. It is the limitation of ORMLite. I asked a separate question on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088970). Quoted: "The field type of orders must be either ForeignCollection<T> or Collection<T> – no other
collections are supported because they are much heavier with many methods to support".