# Save a list of objects to ORMLite database

Tags: java, android, arraylist, ormlite

I am looking for a way to save a list of objects to the database with ORMLite and read upon this question: [Best way to store several ArrayLists in ORMLite for ApplicationSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570578)

And the accepted answer makes sense to me:

```
public class YourClass {
    @GeneratedId
    private int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    private Collection<MyString> bunchOfStrings = new ArrayList<MyString>();
}

public class MyString{
     @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
     private YourClass yourClass;

     @DatabaseField
     private String text;
}
```

And the only thing that I don't understand is this line `private Collection<MyString> bunchOfStrings = new ArrayList<MyString>()`. Why do we save the `ForeignCollectionField` as `Collection<MyString>` instead of as `ArrayList<MyString>`? When working with the `bunchOfStrings` object above, do we always need to cast it to `ArrayList<MyString>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we save the ForeignCollectionField as Collection 
>        instead of as ArrayList?

That was design consideration, excerpt from [doc](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Foreign-Collection)

```
The field type of orders must be either ForeignCollection<T> or Collection<T> – no other
collections are supported because they are much heavier with many methods to support
```

> When working with the bunchOfStrings object above, do we always need
>   to cast it to ArrayList

You dont have to initialize that field, Ormlite will do that. Hence, only available methods are ones present in Collection or ForeignCollection